# Modifying an Nginx regular expression so that it is applied only in some cases

Tags: php, regex, node.js, nginx

I'm creating a hybrid PHP/Node.js application. For PHP, I'm using the Yii framework. Within Node.js, I use express.

PHP is running through Nginx. I use the proxy_pass directive to funnel any request starting with /node to the Node server running on port 3000 (e.g. server.com/node/api is proxyed to server.com:3000/api.)

This works well, for the most part. However, one of the directives in my Nginx configuration file ensures that requests for non-existent static files are not passed on to Yii. Instead, a simple 404 error is returned. The original version of this directive looks like this:

```
location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar|txt)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    #For production servers you can set expires header with a long period
    expires 3M;
}
```

The problem with this directive is that some static files (notably the socket.io client) are served by Node.js. When the browser requests server.com/node/socket.io/socket.io.js, the above rule gets fired, and Nginx returns the 404.

What I want to do is modify the rule so that the 404 is returned only when the request for a static file is NOT preceded by /node/. I've tried various combinations of rules, but none of them seem to work. After consulting the perl regular expression documentation, here's one that I thought might work, but doesn't:

```
location ~* (?<!/node/)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar|txt)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    expires 3M;
}
```

I thought the negative/look-behind part of the rule, `(?<!/node/)`, would work to exclude requests starting with /node/, but it doesn't. Instead, the rule gets fired for both genuinely non-existent js files and for socket.io.js (and various other static files served from Node.js.) So in both cases I get a 404.

How should I change the regular expression so that the rule only gets applied when the request does NOT start with /node/?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I read your question right, you're talking about paths that *don't start with* `/node/`.  That's a lot simpler than matching something that's *not preceded by* something.  This should do it:

```
location ~* ^(?!/node/).*\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar|txt)$ {
```

I think @Pogo almost had it, but as I understand it `location` doesn't include the server name.  The regex start anchor, `^`, matches the position immediately after `.com` (in this case) and before the first slash.  Thus, `^(?!/node/)` ensures that your path doesn't start with `/node/`.

Comment: That did it, Alan! Wow! Your distinction was spot on, and I would have saved myself a lot of time if I'd grasped it earlier on my own. Excellent. Thank you!

(Your regex also has the virtue of being much simpler and not nearly as ugly as the one I did concoct in my response to m.buettner.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the negative lookbehind looks **immediately** in front of the dot. Unfortunately, as far as I know, only .NET supports variable-length lookbehinds. A work around would be, reversing the string, reversing the regex and using a negative lookahead at the end (which can be variable-length):

```
(?!.*/node/)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot write out the full regex right now, because I am typing on a phone.

Comment: This is what I finally came up with:
`(?!(?:(?!\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar|txt)).)*node).*?\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar|txt)`

It seems to work. It's also the most hideous regex I've ever seen :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be because, javascipt doesn't support look behinds fully. You can look ahead at the start to see if it is not /node/ and then continue.

So,

```
.*com(?!/node/).*\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar|txt)$
```

might help you.

Comment: Actually, JS doesn't support lookbehind at all.  But I think you've got the regex almost right.  See my answer for details.